# DB2 Cast DateTime string with "T" separator

Tags: datetime, db2, iso8601

Help me please with the next problem.
I have date time string in the next format(ISO 8601): 1999-12-31T23:59:59
and I need to cast it to TIMESTAMP value. The main problem in 'T' separator character.
I have tried next query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('1999-12-31T23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM ROMAN.EMPLOYEE;
```

and use different format strings, such as, YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS, YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.

Could you provide me correct way to cast this type of strings without any character replacement and substrings.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in function that can format a timestamp in ISO-8601 format in DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows.

As you have probably surmised, you can do this with REPLACE:

```
select 
   TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(REPLACE('1999-12-31T23:59:59','T',' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from
   ROMAN.EMPLOYEE;
```

It's trivial to create a user defined function (UDF) to handle this formatting for you as well so you don't have to out this long string in every query.

It *may* also be possible to do it via XQuery with and `xs:dateTime`, although this would be even more code than just embedding `REPLACE` in the call to `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`.